# Is it possible to keep any media file playing in background even after moving to another tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to keep any media file playing in background even after moving to another tab for example any audio or video file. I have taken video file in my following code.

Comment: Code link- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEGwoB

Comment: I think not, because that tab will be frozen to save resources.

Comment: @Justinas - Yes! it exists, just saw few websites where it's working well. I just thought one solution for it I guess it should work well. What if we will not include that media file in tab 1 opening div else, we will keep that opening div blank and we will put that media file div under the whole tabular parent div.